# Adobe DPS HTML Alert when tapping link that no internet connection available

Tags: html, adobe, adobe-dps

I created an HTML page that has some external links, when the user taps the external link how can I prompt the user that there is no internet connection available? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need some JavaScript and Adobe's [store api](http://www.adobe.com/go/dps-library-store-api) (for banners or store) or [reading api](http://www.adobe.com/go/dps-reading-api) (for html articles or web view in folios). The api provides the singleton object *adobeDPS.deviceService* which can tell you if the device is online or not. Additionally it provides a signal to indicate a change.

For each link element you register an onclick event handler that checks online state and either passes the click through or catches it and gives a message to the user.

The following code could work:

```
<script src="js/AdobeLibraryAPI.min.js"></script>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myLinkChecker.register, false);

    var myLinkChecker = {
        register: function(){
            if (typeof(adobeDPS) !== 'object') {
                console.log("Adobe Library not loaded :-(");
                this.check = function() { return true }    // Fallback
            }

            var linkList = document.querySelectorAll("a, map > area");
            for (var i=0; i < linkList.length; i++){
                var e = linkList[i];
                if (e.hasAttribute('href')) 
                    e.addEventListener('click', myLinkChecker.check, false);
            }
        },

        check: function(ev){
            if (adobeDPS.deviceService.isOnline) {   // let <a> process the click
                console.log("online");
                return true
            } else {          // cancel click event and show message
                event.stopPropagation();
                event.preventDefault();
                alert("Sorry, your device is not online")
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Remote debugging html in DPS apps can be done using iOS developer apps and desktop Safari, or Android apps with Google Chrome.